# linux/python utility to extract attachments from pdf file (Note: other than pdftk)

Tags: python, pdf, amazon-ec2

I am developing an application that downloads some PDF documents from a government website. These documents almost always have attached pdf/xml files that I need to extract. The application is in python and runs on linux. For extracting these documents however, I used to make a system call to pdftk to extract the files. I'm now moving this application to Amazon EC2/Amazon AMI. It turns out that the Amazon AMI does not support pdftk (because of lack of support for gcj-jre). Is there any alternative at all to extract attachments from a pdf file? Either pure python or linux commandline? PyPDF does not seem to have this. And I can't find any other ones either.

P.S. - I don't want to move off the Amazon AMI because I have already configured all the other stuff and its working fine.

P.P.S. - If there is any strong reason (other than absence of pdftk) to move off of Amazon AMI and onto say Ubuntu/CentOS, I would like to know. The application I'm building might end up being pretty massive.

Comment: pdfdetach - http://www.dsm.fordham.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi.pl?topic=pdfdetach&ampsect=1 contained into poppler-utils http://poppler.freedesktop.org/ can replace pdftk without java dependencies

Comment: Thanks Dingo. It seems the Amazon AMI does not get pdfdetach when I install poppler-utils :(

Any how. I built a pyPdf implementation for this now :).

Answer (score 0):

[`pypdf`](https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/) received massive updates in 2022 and development became very active again. The feature you were looking for is about to be added: https://github.com/py-pdf/pypdf/pull/1611